# im having issues with whatsapp:// url scheme

Tags: java, android, android-studio, whatsapp, nativeapplication

***method does not override method from superclass***. how can i fix this error.
im making and android native app for my website.and my website contain a button which amy app defining as unknown url error so i add the code (shared in screenshote) but after that is showing a error and its not working, im doing making this app without any pre knowledge of java or android app development please help me out to solve this issue . everything is working fine instead of whatsapp url

[image: method does not override method from superclass. how can i fix this error. im making and android native app for my website.]

Comment: '    @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    
            boolean overrideUrlLoading = false;
    
            if (url != null && url.startsWith("whatsapp://")) {
    
                view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
    
                overrideUrlLoading = true;
    
            } else {
    
                view.loadUrl(url);
            }
    
            return overrideUrlLoading;
        }
    '

Answer (score 2):

With this code, you're saying that there is a method shouldOverrideUrlLoading in your superclass.
Superclass is the class you extend. Example:

> public class MainActivity extends ExampleClass { }

To [override a method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overriding-in-java/), there needs to be a

> protected void shouldOverrideUrlLoading(){ }

method in ExampleClass.

If you didn't override any class, remove @Override.
If you did and must extend a class, you can't go further without [inheritance](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/inheritance.html) knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

MainActivity and this superclass not has `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method

Comment: what will be the solution please help i m new to this